# Large number of QT warnings when using a precompiled headers approach

Tags: c++, qt, precompiled-headers

I have recently switched a project to making use of precompiled headers due to compilation becoming slow. Before doing so, it built without any significant warnings.

However, after adding all the QT headers I use in my project (of which I use 40-50) to the `stdafx.h` file, during building of the solution, when the `stdafx.h` file gets built I receive a huge number (1000's) of warning relating to QT functions. In particular, I get a lot of "Warning C4251" e.g.

> 1>c:\Qt\5.9\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui/qrawfont.h(154): warning C4251: 'QRawFont::d': class 'QExplicitlySharedDataPointer' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'QRawFont' (compiling source file TitleBar.cpp)

The other two common warning types (albeit far less) are c4800 and c4244.

I am using QT 5.9 64-bit, on a Windows 10 box running VS2015,.

I can obviously just disable them, but I don't really like to do such a thing without understanding why this is happening.

Comment: There is a mismatch between export and import definitions. Like the class at the top of the article: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application It should provide export definition on dynamic library side and import definition of consumer side.

Comment: But I don't have any control of this, as it is all internal to QT.

Comment: I would investigate from TitleBar.cpp and how exactly it includes the type you see the warning about and why there is a mismatch specifically with this set of definitions/compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of cross-platform code creates warnings. It's not always possible to disable them, for example if a parameter is unused, one compiler might warn, if it is artificially used to shut up that warning, another might warn about unreachable code. Then MS warns about things like the C standard string library, which it's often impractical to avoid. You have to remember that MS and Apple have very mixed feeling about something like QT. The last thing they want is to sell undifferentiated platforms for running QT applications on. So there's not much motivation to provide appropriate warnings.